# Android Studio com problema na MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

Eu comecei a utilizar o Android Studio hoje, e ao criar o Projeto do Aplicativo me deparei com um problema: Eu consigo criar, porém a classe MainActivity fica cheia de erros sendo que eu não mudei nada do aplicativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É isso, por acaso vocês já se depararam com esse problema ?
Antes do Android Studio eu usava o Eclipse.
Obrigado!

Comment: Você usa o Gradle? se sim veja se algo muda ao clicar sobre o botão `Sync Project with Gradle Files` ([imagem](http://tools.android.com/_/rsrc/1412965828964/tech-docs/project-sync-issues-android-studio/sync.png)).

Comment: Não, não mudou.

Comment: Pela imagem deve ter algo de errado com a estrutura do diretório, algo incorreto. Tente limpar o cache indo em *File* - *Invalidate Cache*.

Comment: É não deu certo.

Comment: Amigo, tente ir em "build", depois clica em clean , clique em rebuild e depois make project . Após isso, deixa ele realizar as sincronizações, e reinicie o android studio .

Comment: Reinicie, mesmo assim não funcionou..

Comment: Ali em extends, tente estender a Activity .

Comment: Não deu certo .

Comment: Está falando que o problema pode ter sido pela incorreta configuração do daemon. @QMechanic73

Comment: Cara acho que eu não configurei um tal de Gradle, tem que configurar nas Variaveis de Ambientes ? @QMechanic73

Comment: Tenta ler o terminal, as vezes tive problema no R por erros de nomeclatura, por exemplo esse erro aconteceu comigo e sumiu logo após eu corrigir um erro de um xml que eu tinha colocado um traço ao invés de *underline* , outra vez foi corrigido logo após eu corrigir a palavra string que estava escrita "sting"

Comment: tente mudar para extends Activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para resolver isto, faça:

- Clean project localizado em `Build`
- Rebuild project localizado em `Build`, após o término do `Clean Project`.

Lembre-se que a classe `R` é criada automaticamente após o `Build` do seu projeto, ou seja, se algum `Build` seu terminou com erro, essa classe não existirá mais e você terá que dar um `Build` nele novamente.

Comment: Tirou nos outros erros mais a classe R ainda está com error

Comment: Gradle build finished with 101 error(s) in 15 sec

Comment: Certo, os erros são todos na classe R? Preciso que você me mostre seu `AndroidManifest.xml` e o `Build.gradle (app)`.

Comment: Também peço que dê uma olhada na `package` que você está usando em `.java/`.